# MS Access ComboBox Lookup, based on a Field in the same row

Tags: sql, ms-access, combobox

I am trying to figure out the SQL syntax for a ComboBox Lookup in a table in MS Access 2013.  In the Datasheet View of a table, I want to populate a ComboBox with values based on the contents of the field to the left of it on the current row.  For reference, the following SQL statement almost does what I want it to.  What I want to do is replace 'String' with the contents of the field to the left of this ComboBox on the same row of the table.

```
SELECT [Table2].[SubCategories] FROM [Table2] WHERE [Table2].[Category] = 'String';
```

I want to do a lookup on a field in the current row of the table.  What is the syntax to do this?  Do I need to use VBA?  Do I need to use a form?

Comment: Are you trying to do this in a continuous form? If so, it is never going to work the way you hope.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  I am new to Access/SQL and I am thinking about this from a spreadsheet point of view.  Are you saying it is not possible to do in the Datasheet View?  And not even possible in a Continuous Form?  I would like to edit the data in a table.  It seems like a pretty basic thing I want to do, but maybe it does not fit with databases.  Would I need to use a form that only accesses one record at a time?

Comment: Not necessarily, you can display your form with all the records listed, and then include a command button that pops up an edit form for a particular record.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help.  I will look into doing it that way.